# zipkin brave implementation using tomcat server without using profiles

Tags: zipkin, brave

I am looking for a Tracing tool for my spring web-mvc application and i ended up with using Brave-zipkin[https://github.com/openzipkin/brave-webmvc-example/tree/master/webmvc3]. Everything looks fine for me except that, in the given example jetty server deploys the application twice; one for FrontEnd and another for Backend(using two profiles). Whereas my project uses tomcat-server.

Can anyone help me how to use this same tool for deploying in Tomcat-server and start the application without using profiles?

or please suggest any other open source tool for tracing simple monolithic spring-web-mvc application (not spring-boot) and i should be able to see the spans and dependency (eg controllerClass->serviceClass->repositoryClass just like we see under dependency tab of openzipkin web page: http://localhost:9411/zipkin/dependency/)

Answer (score 1):

Brave will work regardless of the server that you choose to use. Remove the jetty configuration from the pom file and use the Tomcat.

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
  <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>2.2</version>
  <configuration>
    <port>${tomcat.port}</port>
    <path>/</path>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```

If you still have trouble or want to know more about zipkin/brave connect to the community via the gitter channel.

P.S. I contribute to OpenZipkin (Zipkin)

Comment: Thank you @zeagord for your inputs.. But, running this way also would need profiles. As mentioned in my question, I am actually looking for a way to run this given project without using profiles so that i still could see spans and dependency as usual. Thanks again!!